# Importing MySQL tables from other database in live site with mysqldump can cause trouble?

Tags: replication, mysql

Scenario: I want to replicate MySQL tables from one database to other database.

Possible best solution: May be to use MySQL Replication feature.
Current solution on what I'm working as workaround (mysqldump) because can't spend time to learn about Replication in current deadline.

So currently I'm using command like this:

```
mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 --single-transaction SourceDb TblName | mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 DestinationDB
```

Based on some tests, it seems to be working fine.
While running above command, I run *ab* command with 1000 requests on destination site and tried accessing the site from browser also.

My concern is for destination live site on which we are importing data with whole table (which will internally drop existing table and create new one with new data).

Can I be sure that live site won't break while this process or is there any risk factor?
If yes then can that be resolved?

Comment: Do you mean schemas on the same server when talking about databases, or are you referring to different MySQL servers?

Comment: For now, I'm seeing for the same MySQL server. In future, I may have more servers.

Comment: If the data is on the same server, you can reference them directly from one schema to another. So why do you want to mimic replication? If you use multiple servers you can use the `FEDERATED` data engine to avoid duplicating the data.

Answer (score 0):

As such you already admitted replication is the best solution here, I'd agree to that.

You said you have 1000 requests on "Destination" side? Are these 1000 connections to Destination read-only? 
Ofcourse dropping and recreating table isn't a right choice here for active connections.

Can suggest one improvement. Instead of directly loading to table, load to different database and swap tables. This should be quicker as far as connections to Destination database/tables are concerned.

- create new table different database

`mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 --single-transaction -hSOURCE_HOST SourceDb TblName | mysql -uuser2 -ppassword2 -hDESTINATION_HOST DB_New`

(Are you sure you don't have "-h " here?)

- Swap the tables

`rename table DB.TblName to DB.old_TblName, DB_New.new_TblName to DestinationDB.TblName;`

If you're on same host (which I dont think so), you might want to use pt-online-schema-change and swap tables!

Comment: - "Are these 1000 connections to Destination read-only?"
What do you mean by read only connection? I think, it's just like mimicking actual user making a request from browser. 

- Swapping table is good alternative. I've prepared that solution also. Thanks! But in my testing, I found that without swapping it's working fine also. So wanted to make sure that mysqldump utility manages such scenario internally or not.

- Databases are on same host for now. I don't know about pt-online-schema-change but we are not going to change schema, will change only data.